# Java - How to access outer class from argument?

Tags: java, parameter-passing

```
public class Outer {
    public void Say(Bar bar) {
        //...
    }
    public Outer(final Foo foo) {
        //...
    }
}

public interface Foo {
    void blah(Bar bar);
}

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer outer = new Outer(new Foo() { 
            @Override
            public void blah(Bar bar) {
                /*trying to access "outer"*/.Say(bar);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What should I do to access "outer"?

Thanks.

<strike>StackOverflow forbade me from posting this because it said my post was mainly code and this line is just a bunch of nonsense. Please ignore it.</strike>

Comment: class Outer doesn’t compile. `Say` looks like a constructor to me (with the capital S), but doesn’t match the class name. Was it meant to be an ordinary method? In that case either the return type or the method name is missing. The method name should begin with a small letter.

Comment: @OleV.V. Oh sorry, I missed a "void".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outer is not reachable. As the instance is created after Foo is created.

I see two ways:
1. Convert the variable outer into a static context.
2. Hand over the variable while calling method blah()

Answer (score 0):

In your example, 'outer' is simply 'this'

Comment: Didn't work. It seems that "this" is resolved as a "Foo" object.

Comment: I think this is not true. The object `outer` is not yet created, hence it cannot be accessed using the `this` qualifier.

Comment: Try it, you are trying to reference the object from inside itself, therefore it is this.

Comment: The question was about accessing the `Outer` object, while using `this` would (if it worked) access the `Foo` object.

Comment: I agree with you on Foo, I missed that.